# Dynamically adding to a listview from an object constructed via input from a dialog

Tags: android, listview, object, dialog, dynamically-generated

So; I have a object that takes in several paramaters:

```
digitalControlObject(int, int, bool bool);
```

I get these objects constructed when a user hits "add" and a dialog appears with options to fill in each of those input paramaters.

However; Is there a way to then take that new object and add it dynamically to a listview on the same fragment?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add it to the array of the `listViewAdapter` and then call `listViewAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged()`

Comment: Can I use a listview and listview adapter in a fragment?

Comment: Yes that's no problem, if you add a listview in the layout file

Comment: Ah, I was under the misunderstanding that listviews were restricted to being edited only within a ListViewActivity.

Comment: No, you can use them and then just normally instantiate them and add the adapter